# How to fix sphinx extension when two sphinx builders generates different doctrees?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

In [my pylatest sphinx
extension](https://gitlab.com/mbukatov/pylatest/blob/master/pylatest/xsphinx/extension.py),
I define custom rst directive `test_action` and custom sphinx builder
`xmlexport` so that when I build a sphinx project with default sphinx html
builder (via `make html`), the `test_action` directives are transformed into
single html table, while with `xmlexport` builder, the directives are just
wrapped in `div` html tags without any additional processing.

To achieve this, the `test_action` directives generates custom doctree nodes
which are either directly translated into html (extending html translator) when
`xmlexport` builder is used, or with `html` builder the custom nodes are
transformed into html table via custom rst transformation class.

I achieve this by checking which builder is used and adding transform classes
accordingly:

```
def pylatest_transform_handler(app):
    if isinstance(app.builder, builders.XmlExportBuilder):
        ...
    else:
        # pylatest transforms for human readable html output,
        # translates pylatest nodes into nice sections or tables
        app.add_transform(transforms.TestActionsTableTransform)
```

In a function which handles [`builder-inited`
event](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/extdev/appapi.html#event-builder-inited)
in my sphinx extension:

```
def setup(app):
    ...
    # pylatest transforms are added based on app.builder value
    app.connect('builder-inited', pylatest_transform_handler)
```

This hack works, but it has one problem: when `html` builder is used, doctree
cached in `_build/doctree/` is diferent compared to one cached after
`xmlexport` builder run. This means that when I run `make html` after I
executed `make xmlexport`, the build fails because sphinx uses wrong doctree.

So the question I have is: How do I make sure that sphinx doctree cache is
regenerated when different builders are used after each other, but kept when
the same builder is used again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that I'm using event `builder-inited`, which is not a good fit for this particular usage.

This causes the transformation to be performed during [*initialization phase* of sphinx build](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/extdev/tutorial.html#build-phases) and because doctree builds are saved after *consistency checks* phase, which follows the initialization one, the effects of the transformation are stored in doctree build files.

When I switched from `add_transform` to `add_post_transform` hooked
on `doctree-resolved` event instead, it started to work as I need: the doctree saved
into the files is the same (as the files are not affected by the transformation) and the transformations happens later during writing phase.

Comment: Based on reply from Komiya Takeshi on [sphinx-users list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/sphinx-users/builder$20doctree%7Csort:date/sphinx-users/ZZptL3IQbRs/1yyXYLguAAAJ)

Comment: Link to a commit fixing the problem in my project: [ecea9bd8](https://gitlab.com/mbukatov/pylatest/commit/ecea9bd8c5c22f52169c44a12cc6ce7e43f64a60)

Comment: Can you say more about how this works? doctree-resolved is emitted *after* post-transforms are run, so your post-transforms are just ignored, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Source: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/_modules/sphinx/environment.html (see the code of `apply_post_transforms`, which applyes post transforms and then emits doctree-resolved)